# INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks

Tags: server, 16.04

I have a AMD FX 8320 8 Core CPU that I have turned into my main file server. I installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 on it with no problems. I also installed KVM/Quem and tested installing a VM from another machine using virt-manager. Everything went well. I also setup Samba and everything went well.

When the system is idle or has been idle for awhile I get the messages below. This same hardware was working fine when I was using as a Ubuntu Desktop. The only difference is I don't have the drivers installed for the Nvidia card because it's a headless server. For the sake of eliminating possibilities I'm in the process of installing the Nvidia drivers from the terminal but I can't get that done because the system freezes during installation.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing the errors below or how to solve?

```
Jul 20 14:56:34 ubuntuNAS kernel: [10214.273076] INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks:
Jul 20 14:56:34 ubuntuNAS kernel: [10214.276215]        2-...: (1 GPs behind) idle=773/1/0 softirq=6581/6581 fqs=1 
Jul 20 14:56:34 ubuntuNAS kernel: [10214.280069]        (detected by 0, t=1500168 jiffies, g=3026, c=3025, q=17432)
Jul 20 14:56:34 ubuntuNAS kernel: [10214.283337] Task dump for CPU 2:
Jul 20 14:56:34 ubuntuNAS kernel: [10214.283340] swapper/2       R  running task        0     0      1 0x00000008
Jul 20 14:56:34 ubuntuNAS kernel: [10214.283346]  ffff88040c6bfe70 0000000000000018 000000001ec93b00 000003d41387e046
Jul 20 14:56:34 ubuntuNAS kernel: [10214.283351]  ffffffff81f36140 ffff88040c6c0000 ffff8804069a0000 ffffffff81eb4ec0
Jul 20 14:56:34 ubuntuNAS kernel: [10214.283356]  ffff88040c6bc000 ffff88040c6bfeb8 ffffffff816c3de7 ffff88040c6bfed0
Jul 20 14:56:34 ubuntuNAS kernel: [10214.283360] Call Trace:
Jul 20 14:56:34 ubuntuNAS kernel: [10214.283371]  [<ffffffff816c3de7>] ? cpuidle_enter+0x17/0x20
Jul 20 14:56:34 ubuntuNAS kernel: [10214.283377]  [<ffffffff810c3fe2>] ? call_cpuidle+0x32/0x60
Jul 20 14:56:34 ubuntuNAS kernel: [10214.283382]  [<ffffffff816c3dc3>] ? cpuidle_select+0x13/0x20
Jul 20 14:56:34 ubuntuNAS kernel: [10214.283387]  [<ffffffff810c42a0>] ? cpu_startup_entry+0x290/0x350
Jul 20 14:56:34 ubuntuNAS kernel: [10214.283392]  [<ffffffff81051714>] ? start_secondary+0x154/0x190
Jul 20 14:56:34 ubuntuNAS kernel: [10214.283397] rcu_sched kthread starved for 1500168 jiffies! g3026 c3025 f0x2 s3 ->state=0x0
```

And these messages:

```
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.418285] INFO: task (snap):4351 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.418886]       Not tainted 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.419641] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421537] (snap)          D ffff8800d89dbcf8     0  4351      1 0x00000000
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421542]  ffff8800d89dbcf8 ffff8800d89dbdd0 ffff88040c6b2940 ffff88040c65c4c0
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421546]  ffff8800d89dc000 ffffffff81e5bb44 ffff88040c65c4c0 00000000ffffffff
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421550]  ffffffff81e5bb48 ffff8800d89dbd10 ffffffff81829a25 ffffffff81e5bb40
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421554] Call Trace:
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421560]  [<ffffffff81829a25>] schedule+0x35/0x80
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421565]  [<ffffffff81829cce>] schedule_preempt_disabled+0xe/0x10
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421569]  [<ffffffff8182b909>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xb9/0x130
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421573]  [<ffffffff8182b99f>] mutex_lock+0x1f/0x30
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421577]  [<ffffffff8111586d>] cgroup_kn_lock_live+0x3d/0xd0
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421591]  [<ffffffff81117360>] __cgroup_procs_write+0x60/0x2f0
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421615]  [<ffffffff8121d9d5>] ? do_filp_open+0xa5/0x100
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421633]  [<ffffffff81117624>] cgroup_procs_write+0x14/0x20
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421645]  [<ffffffff811126ff>] cgroup_file_write+0x3f/0x100
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421662]  [<ffffffff8128c40d>] kernfs_fop_write+0x11d/0x170
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421682]  [<ffffffff8120c9a8>] __vfs_write+0x18/0x40
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421703]  [<ffffffff8120d339>] vfs_write+0xa9/0x1a0
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421722]  [<ffffffff8120dff5>] SyS_write+0x55/0xc0
Jul 20 14:28:21 ubuntuNAS kernel: [ 8520.421743]  [<ffffffff8182db32>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
```

And this: Replace X with a similar message for all 8 cores:

`[14048.299498] NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup -CPU#X stuck for 22s! [systemd-udevd:13603]`

When that last message is running I can't do anything with the system. It is frozen, CPU fan revs up super high and I can't do anything with it.

Comment: I have an identical problem, except I've got a 6 core FX and installing the binary drivers is not a good option, for a variety of reasons. Did you come to any resolution besides the binary drivers?

Comment: Hey stonecrusher. Unfortunately i ended up switching to CentOS7 server. Everything works fine...samba, kvm/qemu, etc (samba took some extra work with all the permissions for centos). I think the problem is tied to the kernel (3.x vs 4.x) but I cannot confirm because after I got everything working in centos7 i did not test alternate builds.