# High load, low cpu utilisation - system crashing periodically

Tags: system-installation, configuration, crash

I have just installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 16.04. The system falls over regularly with message below in syslog.

```
INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks: 
    2-...: (1 GPs behind) idle=363/1/0 softirq=167130/167130 fqs=7845837 
    (detected by 0, t=7845872 jiffies, g=197552, c=197551, q=225464)
```

Uptime shows the following load:

```
 09:10:42 up 22:36,  1 user,  load average: 4.04, 4.02, 4.00
```

Top shows similar despite high idle usage

```
top - 09:11:17 up 22:37,  1 user,  load average: 4.12, 4.05, 4.01
Tasks: 214 total,   2 running, 212 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 97.3 id,  2.7 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  :  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  8112956 total,  4986392 free,  1399292 used,  1727272 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  8325628 total,  8325628 free,        0 used.  6313608 avail Mem
```

Free information shows plenty of RAM available.

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7922        1366        4865          35        1690        6161
Swap:          8130           0        8130
```

I don't see any I/O issues from iotop:

```
Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :       0.00 B/s
Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       0.00 B/s
```

The only consistency is that it seems to be cpu2 that causes the stalls. What else should I be looking at to determine the reason for crashes?

Comment: Looks similar to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/801004/info-rcu-sched-detected-stalls-on-cpus-tasks No answers on that one either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was caused by a missing graphics card driver. In this case for nvidia. I installed these drivers and disabled UEFI safe boot and have been crash free for over a day.